# Windows 10 samba NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, samba, windows-10

I maintain a small business with a ubuntu 14.04 server running samba 4.3.9-Ubuntu. Everything worked fine with Windows 7, after upgrade to Windows 10 only those can log in to a PC who already logged in once before the upgrade.

For everyone else all I get in the error logs is

```
NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
```

and on the client side it says, that no login servers are available.

I already tried disabling SMB2/3 but this does not help.

I am really confused that some users work (those who already have their profile synced to the pc) and the others don't.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, it seems I need to enable SMB1 only on the server side using server max protocol = NT1

Comment: Enabling SMB1 is not a good idea. This protocol is nearly 30 yrs old and allows passwordless logins, it is not safe !
Using Samba4 and up you should have no issues connecting without SMB1 enabled. This is the reason we are upgrading all samba servers from 3.6 to 4.2

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
smbclient -L <hostname> -m SMB2
```